# Adding return values of two sum() e.g sum()+sum() and store it new list

Tags: python, list, sum

```
a = map(int, raw_input().split())
n = len(a)
for i in range(0, n):
    start_sum = sum(a[0:i+1])  # to calculate sum of first i
    last_sum = sum(a[-(n-i):]) # to calculate sum of last n-i
```

now I have to store the sum of **start_sum** and **last_sum** and store it in **new list b** with index same as **i** .Like this below

```
b[i] = start_sum + last_sum
```

How to implement this. I am new to Python. Any help will be great.

Comment: `for i in range(0, n)`:  n should be `len(a)`. You probably entered less numbers the second time. Please provide a non-interactive [mcve]; BTW `split()` on your sum won't work either...

Comment: Can't you just create  2 empty list before for loop and then you can append the results to it. That way you can save your start_sum and las_sum to 2 different lists

Comment: Please edit your post to include the full text of the error, including the traceback.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One solution could be:

```
a = map(int, raw_input().split())
b = []
for i in range(0, n):
    start_sum = sum(a[0:i+1])  # to calculate sum of first i
    last_sum = sum(a[-(n-i):]) # to calculate sum of last n-i
    b.append(start_sum + last_sum)
```

Other solutions are possible...
The problem you had, was that b had not been created as list with n places, so putting something at place `i` will fail.

Answer (score 0):

The ith value will be in both the first i values and the last n-i values. The rest of the values will be in exactly one set. So if you want the same functionality, you can just do:

```
a_sum = sum(a)
b = [x+a_sum for x in a]
```